# Android Studio on Mac

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ide

When creating a new project in Android Studio, before I do anything, I get this error:

Error:java.io.IOException: Operation not supported

> Operation not supported

Even after a gradle sync and update I still get this error. Anyone got a clue? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting it to create the app on my desktop stopped that error.

Comment: Thanks for this pointer. I was trying to use a Network share to hold the projects and the error wasn't helpful at all. I moved the project back to local storage and it compiled without any problems.

Comment: is there any other solution?

Comment: I'd also like to add that I was opening this project on a Network share, causing the same exact error, and once I copied it to my machine, it built just fine.

Comment: I had the same issue – I stored the project in a Google Drive folder, but Gradle kept failing. I moved it to a local folder, and it was working. I suspect that either `gradle` or `java` can't work with a network drive for some reason...

Comment: Tried to understand why it doesn't work with Google Drive. Didn't find anything that would differentiate a Google Drive folder from a regular folder. **So** weired.